# golang encrypt cipher.Block / AES key itself

Tags: go, encryption, aes, encryption-asymmetric

I'm using an AES key of type `cipher.Block` generated by using `crypto/aes` package with below func:

```
aesBlock, err := aes.NewCipher(randKey)
```

I'm using this to encrypt a particular set of data but afterward I want to encrypt `aesBlock` itself with a Public Key, so that I can store and later decrypt with the asymmetric Private Key. However, I'm having a tough time finding the best way to encrypt `aesBlock`. Obviously this needs to be reversible so that I can use it to decrypt the previously mentioned data.

The [func EncryptOAEP](https://golang.org/pkg/crypto/rsa/#EncryptOAEP) from `crypto/aes` seems like a good fit, as it takes a `*PublicKey`, however the `msg` parameter is of type `[]byte` and my AES key is of type `cipher.Block`. Not sure a direct conversion is possible or even a good idea.

Any ideas?

Comment: Why would you try to encrypt `aesBlock` itself? Just encrypt and store `randKey` and create a new `aesBlock` as needed.

Comment: Will using `randKey` recreate the same `aesBlock`? I guess I thought that this was more of a salt to help randomize `aesBlock` further.

Comment: Welp, you are correct - I just tested. I can't believe I didn't realize that. Thanks for shedding light.

Answer (score 0):

As Adrian pointed out in the comments, the solution is simpler than I thought. All you need to do is encrypt and store the `randKey`. Regenerating the `aesBlock` with decrypted `randKey` produces the same results.